# i want bind src of an iframe from controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, iframe

I want to set `src` of an `iframe` tag using angular controller.
Well my source is need to be passed through a filter first. Something like this below

```
<iframe ng-src="{{source| youtubeEmbedUrl}}">
</iframe>
```

`youtubeEmbedUrl` is an filter. Let's not come to that.

Now what i want is upon ng-click of the following div, the src of `<iframe>` above should be set along with the filter.

```
<div ng-click="playVideo($index, video)">{{clickable_text}}</div>
```

I thought mixing jQuery for accomplishing the task inside angular controller. So here is my unsuccessful attempt inside the controller.

```
$("#id_of_the_iframe_div").html('<iframe ng-src="{{'+videoUrl+' | youtubeEmbedUrl}}"></iframe>');
```

`videoUrl` contains url of the video i want to play.
Any help would be great.

Comment: you have to compile it. don't use jquery like that in angular.

Comment: yeah i got it that it need to be compiled, but i was pretty desperate to try it after a lot brain storming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, do not use jQuery at all! Use an `ng-if` to display the iFrame - and use do your `filter` inside the controller:

```
$scope.playVideo = function(index, video) {
    //Obviously some other stuff happens here
    //The jist is - do your logic in here to get your source
    //Trigger a variable to show the iframe
    $scope.showVideo = true; //for showing the iFrame
    $scope.videoUrl = $filter('youtubeEmbedUrl')($scope.videoUrl); //Dont forget to inject $filter in your controller
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<iframe ng-if="showVideo" ng-src="{{videoUrl}}"></iframe>
```

Comment: hey that's a nice answer, now one thing more. I actually have those iframes in `ng-repeat`. So i am giving the src as `videoUrl$index`. Can you please tell me how to change ` $scope.videoUrl ` equivalent to  `{{videoUrl$index}}`

Comment: `{{videoUrl + $index}}` @sagarpatro

Comment: inside controller like `$scope.videoUrl+index`. WIll it do?